# How we can access the rotation angle from matrix?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, matrix, svg

Can please anybody explain me how will i get the x,y and rotation angle for the following image from its matrix attribute ?

```
<image
   y="-136.18584"
   x="343.87161"
   id="image3000"
   xlink:href="file:///C:/Users/gaurav/Documents/testing.jpg"
   height="369"
   width="360"
   transform="matrix(0.75329963,0.65767748,-0.65767748,0.75329963,0,0)" />
```

I am so much weak in maths, so please help  me out ?

Comment: Why is this tagged c# and javascript? Shouldn't it be SVG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Coordinate Systems, Transformations and Units – SVG 1.1 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) and if my pocket calculator is right, it is about 41 degrees, counter clockwise.

The first value `0.75329963` is the cos(theta), where theta is the sought angle. So you have only to calculate the inverse cosine for that value and have your result.

x&y define the centre of the rotation. The exact values depend on what was the developers intention. In other words: where to place the image after rotating it. Their effect also depends on the image size.

Comment: Thanks , but if u will explain me how it comes 41 degree than it will really helpful for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arne , can u please tell me how we will calculate x and y  from this matrix